# showing only few lines of command output in emacs shell

Tags: shell, emacs

Is there an option or extension to restrict command output in Emacs shell or eshell to just few lines and show the rest either when pressing a special key or showing full output in a separated window?

I can redirect the output to a new buffer, but that requires to know in advance that the output is big. What would be nice instead is to restrict output to, for example, half widow height so unexpectedly long output does not clatter the shell window.